# Подсветка найденых слов в PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

Посоветуйте, как сделать подсветку найденного контента в PDF документе.

Делаю приложение для WindowsPhone 8.1, в основе которого отображение PDF документов. На клиентской стороне конвертирую постранично документ в картинки. Нужно допилить поиск, сделав подсветку найденной строки. Приложение достаточно шустро работает, если даже пользователь постранично листает большой текст+картинки документ (до 1000 страниц). 
Использую Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer for .NET в качестве базовой библиотеки для рендеринга и навигации.

Comment: Тогда вам, вероятно, нужно обратиться к документации или разработчикам `Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer` за информацией.

Comment: @Михаил Ефимченко: О, отлично. Вы бы написали это ответом, чтобы другим польза была.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нашёл, сделал через

```
SearchResultRegion region = page.TransformRegion(searchResultItem.Region, bm.Width, bm.Height, renderingSettings);
```

потом region.Blocks залил цветом.